# Solution of $x^2(y')^2-2(xy-4)y'+y^2=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm currently trying to solve the differential equation:
$$x^2y'^2-2(xy-4)y'+y^2=0,$$
but up to now I've had no succes. I rewrote it as

$$(xy'-y)^2+8y'=0$$

and substituted

$$v=yx$$

hoping that the equation would become seperable. Unfortunately this only works well for linear equations. So I got:
$$x^2v'^2-4vv'x+4v^2+8xv'-8v=0.$$
This seems pretty hard to solve. I don't know if there is a better substitution, or simply a better method to solve this one ?

Comment: The substitution $y/x$ may be more useful, since its derivative is $(x y'-y)/x^2$.

Comment: @Nick probably you should use as mentioned above, $v= \frac{y}{x}$. This gets us $x^2v' = xy'-y$, and also that $y ' = \frac{x^2v'+y}{x} = xv' + v$

Comment: @semiclassical, what might me the motivation for this substitution? Is it that by dividing the entire equation bij x^2 that you see this ?

Comment: That and a measure of intuition. It also amounts to writing $y=v x$, which based on your ODE seems like a good change of variables.

Comment: @semiclassical, your substitution yields $x^4(v')^2+8xv'+8v=0$. It seems slightly better, but stil hard to solve :p

Comment: Can't say I disagree! I was trying to take advantage of your factorization, but David's answer below does a better job on that front.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your rearrangement looks so handy i wondered what happens if we set:
$$
v = xy'-y
$$
this gives
$$
v' =xy''
$$
the equation
$$
v^2 +8y' =0
$$
may be differentiated to give
$$
2vv'+8y''=0
$$
multiplying by $x$ and factoring out $2$ gives
$$
xvv' + 4v'=0
$$
i.e.
$$
(xv+4)v'=0
$$

Comment: So then I could go with the cases $v'=0$ and $v=-4/x$ ?

Comment: i think that idea might be worth exploring. however the differentiation might introduce some complication.  $v'=0$ gives the family of straight lines $y=ax+b$ subject to the constraint that $b^2=8a$. so these lines should define an envelope of the one-parameter family of solutions of $v=-\frac4{x}$ which are something like $y=x(c+\frac2{x^2})$. can you investigate this?

Comment: I get the constraint that $b^2=-8a$. For the other equation I'm looking for a solution ...

Comment: you should find $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) = -\frac4{x^3}$

Comment: If I fill in $y=ax+b$ in $(xy'-y)^2+8y'=0$ I get my $b^2+8a=0$. Now solving the second equation.

Comment: And for the envelope you have $y=2/x$. :)

Comment: my calculation agrees with that result, so well done!